# Subrings, submodules, and flatness

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, modules, flatness

Let $R$ be a ring, and $S$ a subring of $R$. Let $M$ be a right $R$-module, and $N$ a right $S$-submodule of $M$. If $N$ is flat (or faithfully flat) as a right $S$-module, does it then follow that the multiplication map
$$
N \otimes_S R \to NR \subseteq M
$$
is an isomorphism? Is flatness necessary for this to happen?

Comment: When $N=R$ and $S=Z$, (and either if we forget the fact that $S$ is a subring of $R$ or we restrict ourselves to characteristic zero case so that $Z$ is automatically included in $R$) the condition you are looking for is that $R$ is solid (c.f. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/core+of+a+ring )

Answer (score 4):

No it need not be an isomorphism. Something more than flatness is required. For example, taking $M$ and $N$ to be copies of the ring $R$ you are asking for the multiplication $R\otimes_SR\to R$ to be an isomorphism. If $S$ is a field and $R$ is an associative $S$-algebra then this fails unless $R=S$.